# User List to Remove keys from Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, user-input

What is the best way to get a user to be able to enter a list(or singular) number to remove a string key entry from a dictionary?

so far this is where I am.

My dictionary to remove the values from(the dictionary is generated so will vary).

```
d = {'Seven': 22, 'Six': 0, 'Three': 35, 'Two': 0, 'Four': 45, 'Five': 34, 'Eight': 0}
```

1) So how do I get the input is my first query. This was my attempt but failed.

```
>>> s = raw_input('1 2 3 4')
1 2 3 4
>>> numbers = map(str, s.split())
>>> numbers
[]

>>> s = raw_input('1 2 3 4')
1 2 3 4
>>> numbers = map(int, s.split())
>>> numbers
[]
```

2) How would I convert the ints to word form? Here the range is limited there will never be greater than 20 entries per dictionary.
So my initial thought was to create a key of sorts to interpret the info.

```
e = {'One': 1, 'Two': 2, 'Three': 3, 'Four': 4}
```

and this works not as expected removing only one entry.

```
>>> e = {'One': 1, 'Two': 2, 'Three': 3, 'Four': 4}
>>> {k:v for k,v in e.items() if v!=(1 and 3)}
{'Four': 4, 'Two': 2, 'One': 1}
```

My intention is to remove the values from d and not e. Its also not practical as I don't know how many entries the user will enter so using 'and' statements seems wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the parameters of `raw_input` are just for display. You need to enter it yourself:

```
>>> s = raw_input("Enter a sequence of number: ")
Enter a sequence of number: 1 2 3 4
>>> print s
1 2 3 4
```

Now, you can just use a list to map it:

```
m = ['1':'One', '2':'Two', '3':'Three', .., '10':'Ten']
```

**Edit** Here is how to convert it:

```
e = [v for k, v in m.items() if k in s]
```

Third, dictionary comprehensions (or 'comprehensions' in general) weren't meant to modify an existing object, but to create a new one. The closest you can get is to make it act like a filter, and reassign the results back to `d`

```
d = {k:v for k, v in d.items() if k not in e}
```

Comment: How did you convert user input s to e?

Comment: @sayth Updated my answer with a few changes.

Comment: Something about this doesn't seem to work  >>> s = raw_input("Enter Numbers: ")
Enter Numbers: 1 2 3 4
>>> s
'1 2 3 4'
>>> numbers = map(int, s.split())
>>> numbers
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> m = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight']
>>> e = [i for i in m if i in s]
>>> e
[]
>>> e = [i for i in m if i in numbers]
>>> e
[]

Comment: @sayth My bad. Hang on a sec.